# Mako Dynamic Template Inheritance

Tags: python, django-templates, pyramid, mako

We had this code and it worked fine.  After doing a refactor, it doesn't work anymore.  Like the comment says, we only want to inherit from a base page if the request isn't an ajax request.  To do this, we pass a parameter to the template, and, based on the parameter, we inherit or not.

View.py

```
class Router(object):
    def __init__(self, request):
        self.request = request

    @view_config(route_name="home")
    def get(self):
        template = "home.mak"
        value = {'isPage':self.request.is_xhr is False}
        return render_to_response(template, value, request=self.request)
```

Template.mak

```
##conditional to determine with the template should inherit from the base page
##it shouldn't inherit from the base page is it is being inserted into the page using ajax
<%!

   def inherit(context):
       if context.get('isPage') == True:
           return "base.mak"
       else:
           return None
%>
<%inherit file="${inherit(context)}"/>
```

Currently, the error is Undefined does not have attribute **__*getitem*__**.  If we change ${inherit(context)} to ${inherit(value)} we get global variable value is undefined.

Comment: Can you try putting all the logic into the inherit tag? Just to take the function call out of the equation: ${'base.mak' if context.get('isPage') else None}

Comment: I don't think that was the problem.  We did a pretty sizable refactor and the above code is working again.  I'm guessing the context passed in wasn't initialized or there was a syntax error in one of the templates.

Comment: As an aside, the request object has a property called is_xhr which is true if the request is asynchronous.  We're using this property to determine if we need to load the full page or not.  So is_page = self.request.is_xhr is False

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just ran into the same problem, same use case as well actually (render layout or not depending the request being an XHR).

You can apparently access the `request` through `context`, so you can avoid having to split this tiny bit of logic over two places (view and template):

```
<%!
   def inherit( context ):
       if not context.get('request').is_xhr:
           return 'layout_reports.mako'
       else:
           return None
%>
<%inherit file="${inherit(context)}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

We did a pretty sizable refactor and the above code is working again. I'm guessing the context passed in wasn't initialized or there was a syntax error in one of the templates.

As an aside, the request object has a property called is_xhr which is true if the request is asynchronous. We're using this property to determine if we need to load the full page or not. So is_page = self.request.is_xhr is False

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure whether this works or not

```
 %if not request.is_xhr:
 <inherit file='base.mako'/>
 %endif
```

Aassuming request is available in context

Comment: This doesn't work.  Inheritance can't be decided while the template is being rendered.  It has to be declared in a module level block, otherwise the command is ignored.  http://docs.makotemplates.org/en/latest/syntax.html#module-level-blocks  Also, I don't think the request gets passed to the template, so this will generate an exception.

Comment: I was wrong about the request getting passed to the template.